# Asp .net core 2.0 MVC respond to URL format

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

Let me just begin with saying that I am a beginner to Asp.net core MVC.

I am trying to create a controller action, WhoAreYou, that should either return a Html view or Json depending on the URL format.

So:

```
base/Information/WhoAreYou => Html view views/Information/WhoAreYou.cshtml
and base/Information/WhoAreYou.json => {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Is there an good way of doing this without having to specify format as an url parameter? I.e base/Information/WhoAreYou?format=json. And then simply having an if statement in the controller action:

```
public IActionResult WhoAreYou(string format)
{
    if(format == "json")
        return Json(new {message = "Hello World"})
    return View();
}
```

And also is there some way of specifying a template somewhere so I don't have to write Json code in the controller.
For example when I have been working with Ruby on Rails you could have different view templates for different formats which would then specify their own individual content.

In this case:

```
views/Information/WhoAreYou.cshtml
views/Information/WhoAreYou.json
```

Comment: This is just personal opinion, but I think the best approach would be to have a separate actions for json/html. Is there any reason you need the same action to return either json or html?

Comment: No not really, I just like that structure. I.e its the same resource just different formats. But doing it your way is certainly reasonable.